# pandas taking average of certain rows while keeping others unchanged

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two dataframes: df1 and df2.

df1 contains daily data and has 4 columns: date, id, value1, value2;

df2 contains dates on which certain events happened to an id; it has two columns: date and id.

df2 is a subset of the date and id columns in df1

for each row in df2, I would like to find the row with the same date and id in df1, and get the rows from date-1 to date+1 for that id, take the average and replace the previous three rows.

For example, if I have date = 3 and id = A from df2, I would like to find rows with date in (2, 3, 4) and id = A in df1, take the average of these rows and replace these three rows with the resulting one row.

## df1:

```
index date id value1 value2
  0    1    A  0.1     0.2
  1    2    A  0.2     0.3
  2    3    A  0.3     0.4
  3    4    A  0.4     0.5
  4    5    A  0.5     0.6
  5    1    B  0.1     0.2
  6    2    B  0.2     0.3
  7    3    B  0.3     0.4
  8    4    B  0.4     0.5
  9    5    B  0.5     0.6
```

## df2

```
index date id
  0     3    A
  1     3    B
```

## desired output

```
index date id value1 value2
  0    1    A  0.1     0.2
  1    3    A  0.3     0.4
  2    5    A  0.5     0.6
  3    1    B  0.1     0.2
  4    3    B  0.3     0.4
  5    5    B  0.5     0.6
```

Comment: You're kind of spelling out the solution yourself: "I would like to find rows with date in (2, 3, 4) and id = A in df1"... Coupled with the remainder of your detail, what does your attempt look like? You've broken down the problem, now how do you translate that into code? Think of filtering and using `pandas.Series.isin`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Notes:***

- It looks like you want to calculate the 3 period rolling mean with a centered window.
- Then slice it for only the relevant rows from list of events (`df2`)
- Finally, update the first dataframe (`df1`) with those values

***Plan:***

- use `pd.DataFrame.rolling` with parameters `window=3` and `center=True`
- because I need to update later, I'm going to place the columns `['date', 'id']` in the index.
- since `df2` isn't doing anything other than acting as an index, I'm going to make it an index explicitly
- finally, I'll update the dataframe with `loc` and `reset_index`

---

```
d1 = df1.set_index(['date', 'id'])
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df2.values.T)

d1.loc[idx] = d1.groupby(level='id', group_keys=False).rolling(3, center=True).mean()

d1.reset_index()

   date id  value1  value2
0     1  A     0.1     0.2
1     2  A     0.8     0.3
2     3  A     0.5     0.5
3     4  A     0.4     0.8
4     5  A     0.5     0.6
5     1  B     0.1     0.2
6     2  B     0.2     0.3
7     3  B     0.3     0.4
8     4  B     0.4     0.5
9     5  B     0.5     0.6
```

***setup***

```
# Note that changed the values of
# the 2nd row of value1 and 
# the 4th row of value2 in order to
# highlight that this works
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'date': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'value1': [0.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
        'value2': [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [3, 3], 'id': ['A', 'B']})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.concat([df1[(df1['id'] == row['id']) & df1['date'].isin([row['date'], row['date'] - 1, row['date'] + 1])] for _, row in df2.iterrows()])
```

This will result in:

```
       date id  value1  value2
index                         
1         2  A     0.2     0.3
2         3  A     0.3     0.4
3         4  A     0.4     0.5
6         2  B     0.2     0.3
7         3  B     0.3     0.4
8         4  B     0.4     0.5
```